# Lia algebra strings

Tags: lie-algebras

Let $a,b$ be roots ($a\ne \pm b$) of a Lie algebra $g$ of type $X$, where $X$ can be classic or exceptional $(A,B,C,D,E,F,G)$. It is well known that the length of an $a$-string through $b$ is at most 4.

What are all types of $g$ such that:

1) $a+b$ can be a root and $a+2b$ is not a root?

2) $a+2b$ can be a root and $a+3b$ is not a root?

3) $a+3b$ can be a root?

Thanks!

Comment: You asked the same in Math.SE, and if I recall correctly, you even got an answer---I cannot find that question now, though. Can you elaborate on why the answer you got did not satisfy you?

Comment: @Mariano: I haven't received an answer. The external link is http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15612/length-of-root-strings
Thanks.

Comment: On the other hand, you ignored the (reasonable) request to clarify what "scenery" means.  Until you say that, you won't get a good answer, because no one knows what it means.  I'm downvoting for lack of clarity; I might change my mind if you define "scenery."

Comment: @Ben: I did not ignored the request. I just haven't seen it. That's totally different.

Comment: So, what you're saying is that you posted this without reading the comments on the Math.SE post (the relevant comment was written 2 hours before you posted this)?  That's even worse.

Comment: And the question is still ill-defined. Do you want all g where some such pair exists?

Comment: @Ben $a$ and $b$ are arbitraries, I guess it is clear in the first part of the question. 

Comment: No, it's not clear in the first part of of the question.  If you ask "for which g does this property of a and b hold," you have to specify if you mean some pair of a and b, all pairs of a and b, or something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3) is only possible if $a$ is 3 times longer than $b$, so it only happens in $G_2$.

2) is only possible if $a$ is 2 times longer than $b$ (or if $a=b+a'$ for $a'$ a root 3 times longer), so it happens in all non-simply laced types ($B,C,F$ and $G$).

1) happens in every simple root system other than $A_1$, since this happens whenever $a$ and $b$ are the same length and not orthogonal.

Comment: if b and c are the short and long simple roots of G_2, and you take a=b+c, then 2) is satisfied.  What's imprecise about that?

Comment: @Chris: Pick $a$ and $b$ such that $a+3b$ is a root.  Now, do a substitution, setting new $a$ to old $a+b$.  You never specified that $a$ and $b$ had to be simple.